# Titanium - Slide menu like Groupon

Tags: ios, menu, slider, titanium, groupon

Can you show me a method for make a slider menu like Groupon apps in Titanium??

Video example -->[click here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R_NkdNA33oY)

I have tried to use two scroller: one scrollableView in the page and a ScrollView in the menu, but this approach it's too difficult and redundant...
Someone can shows me easiest way or a tutorial?? 
Thanks!
Sorry for my english

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Native Slider Menu working for both android and iOS

https://github.com/viezel/NappSlideMenu

Thanks

Comment: i can't run the file :\

Comment: Are you following the tutorial of installing titanium modules?

Comment: ..mmm, but this module is not like the groupon's menu :\

Answer (score 2):

I think that this is what you are looking for, because its exactly what I was looking for (Groupon like menu).

https://github.com/TomThorpe/UIScrollSlidingPages

Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

you can also check out the Appcelerator Marketplace (https://marketplace.appcelerator.com/listing?q=menu#!/list/page/1/search=menu)

I checked - there's one free in there. I do like @Wahhab_mirza open source link. FREE is the best. but in case you don't want to deal with compiling it - take a pick at the Marketplace.